# How to embed all Facebook page photos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, embed, photo

I want to embed all of the photos posted on my Facebook page onto my website.

Using [Galleria](https://github.com/aiaio/galleria-facebook) i've managed to embed an album from my Facebook page on to my website, but i would like to embed all of the photos in one gallery. This would be a lot cleaner than having multiple albums showing on the same webpage and save the hassle of having to alter the script every time a new ablum is uploaded.
On Facebook, when you click the photos tab found underneath the banner photo, you are given two options, photos and albums. It is the photos found in the photos section, which is all of the photos posted that i would like to embed in to one gallery.

This is the photos section in the page that i run. [Photos section on Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/LUUCCkayak/photos_stream?tab=photos_stream).

The first photo in that stream has a URL of - ..../photos/pb.394061020620308.-2207520000.1437521944./1131415663551503/?type=3

The album that i've already managed to get to work has a URL of - 
..../photos/a.1125399300819806.1073741845.394061020620308/1125399444153125/?type=3

The instructions for Galleria state that the 17 digit number after the a. is the album ID number, which is what i've used to get the single album to work. For the album that i've managed to get to work, this is 1125399300819806.

The 15 digit number at the end of the URL is the ID for the photo currently showing. In the example i've given, this is either 1125399444153125 or 1131415663551503.

I've tried using 394061020620308 - this has turned out to be the album ID for the page profile album.

I've also tried -

```
394061020620308
-2207520000
2207520000
1437518966
2207520000.1437518966
-2207520000.1437518966
394061020620308.1437518966
394061020620308.-2207520000
394061020620308.2207520000
```

But i've had no luck. Can anyone suggest anything that will work?

Or another script that will work?
Or another service that will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but to get a list of the album ids you can query the Graph API via Graph Explorer:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=LUUCCkayak%2Falbums

By issuing the `/LUUCCkayak/albums` call, I receive the following result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Timeline Photos",
      "created_time": "2012-02-27T10:51:18+0000",
      "id": "396826650343745"
    },
    {
      "name": "Christie Cup 2015",
      "created_time": "2015-05-17T20:52:06+0000",
      "id": "1125399300819806"
    },
    {
      "name": "Welsh Weekend 2015",
      "created_time": "2015-05-14T15:03:44+0000",
      "id": "1123618930997843"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mobile Uploads",
      "created_time": "2014-02-13T17:33:54+0000",
      "id": "827630280596711"
    },
    {
      "name": "Semester 2 Inter trips",
      "created_time": "2015-04-01T16:50:13+0000",
      "id": "1096724827020587"
    },
    {
      "name": "Salford Polo 28/02/2015",
      "created_time": "2015-03-03T19:54:40+0000",
      "id": "1079617935397943"
    },
    {
      "name": "Snowboating + a little Tees",
      "created_time": "2015-02-01T23:23:59+0000",
      "id": "1061377837221953"
    },
    {
      "name": "Lakes Weekend 2015",
      "created_time": "2015-01-26T13:29:26+0000",
      "id": "1057442500948820"
    },
    {
      "name": "Upper Tees day!!!!!",
      "created_time": "2014-12-07T20:07:37+0000",
      "id": "1020096474683423"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dee Day",
      "created_time": "2014-11-24T08:19:21+0000",
      "id": "1010340185659052"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC go to the Middle Tees",
      "created_time": "2014-11-16T21:35:21+0000",
      "id": "1005981122761625"
    },
    {
      "name": "Leven and Kent Day",
      "created_time": "2014-11-10T18:55:55+0000",
      "id": "1001793183180419"
    },
    {
      "name": "Profile Pictures",
      "created_time": "2012-02-23T18:24:13+0000",
      "id": "394220000604410"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cover Photos",
      "created_time": "2012-03-15T23:53:44+0000",
      "id": "409649069061503"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC goes to the Tyne Tour",
      "created_time": "2014-11-03T12:52:22+0000",
      "id": "997087716984299"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC go to the Lune",
      "created_time": "2014-10-28T00:04:16+0000",
      "id": "992887274071010"
    },
    {
      "name": "Wharfe Day",
      "created_time": "2014-10-13T14:26:00+0000",
      "id": "983636668329404"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC @ The Burrs",
      "created_time": "2014-10-05T22:46:24+0000",
      "id": "977730608920010"
    },
    {
      "name": "Faces of LUUCC 2014/15",
      "created_time": "2014-09-28T21:43:52+0000",
      "id": "972949889398082"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC Do: BUCS Slalom 2014",
      "created_time": "2014-02-15T23:37:09+0000",
      "id": "828915663801506"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC Do: Tyne Tour 2013",
      "created_time": "2013-11-04T12:47:44+0000",
      "id": "762842167075523"
    },
    {
      "name": "LUUCC do: Surfing",
      "created_time": "2013-10-13T20:54:23+0000",
      "id": "748712981821775"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "NzQ4NzEyOTgxODIxNzc1",
      "before": "Mzk2ODI2NjUwMzQzNzQ1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good shout. I didn't know that this could be done. But what i would like is for all of these photos to be within the same gallery. I was under the impression that Facebook might have stored them in a similar fashion to an album.
Would it be easier if i ported the photos to a different website where i could have them all in one album?

Comment: I don't understand... They ARE stored in albums, as the response clearly shows. I don't know how galleria works internally, so please check if it offers the functionality you desire. This is not a Facebook issue.

Comment: I'd prefer it so that the photos are constantly updated to the latest photos and keeping the photos on Facebook is the best solution. As Facebook is the site that all of the photos are shared for our group and on will continue to do so for the foreseeable future. So using Facebook for the gallery means that there is no faff with copying photos to a particular website periodically. So is there a better gallery script out there for this?
But like in my first comment, i'm not adverse to using another site to get the photos in the website.